# how to enable onclick back and function wont auto run

Tags: jquery

```
//my function 
function handler(){
//do something.
}

//disable my onclick
$(".Dicon").prop('onclick',null).off('click');

//using this code to enable , it will auto ran the function
$(".Dicon").prop('onclick',handler);
```

i am using the code to disable all my class on click , but i need to enable them at some point , how i gonna to enable them back ?

when i use my code to enable the on click back , it auto run the function , anyway i could enable them back and the function won't run?

Answer (score 0):

TRy trigger():

```
$(".Dicon").prop('onclick',handler).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the "executableness" in a variable?

```
var onClickOn = true; //initial state

function handler (event) {
    if ( onClickOn ) {
        //do stuff
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault(); // don't do anything
        event.stopPrpagation(); // really don't do anything

        return false; //make sure you don't do anything
    }
}

$(".Dicon").on('click',handler);
```

now you can control the handler by changing the value of `onClickOn`.

An other possible solution is to delegate the event with a small trick

```
$('body').on('click', ".Dicon:not(.noClick)", handler);
```

This way you can control the event by adding and removing the `noClick` class to your links.